# Python Tflearn machine learning Optimiser, loss and parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

After fixing my code and prepare my data for training I've found myself in front of 2 question.

**Background**: 
I have data made of date (one entry per minute) for the first column and congestion (value, between 0 and 200) for the 2nd. My goal is to feed it to my neural network and so be able to predict for the next week the congestion at each minute (my dataset is more than 10M of entry, I shouldn't have problem of lack of data for training).

**Problem**:
I now have two question. First about the loss, optimizer and linear. It seem there is a certain number of them and they all have a domain where they are better than the other, which one would you recommend for this project? (Currently on my test I use Adam as an optimizer and mean_square as loss and linear for activation).

My second question is more like an error that I have (may be linked to me using the wrong loss/optimizer). When using my code (10 000 data of training for now) I have an accuracy of 0, a low loss (0.00X) and a bad prediction (not even close to the reality). Do you have any idea of where it could come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called time series prediction (given data at time *t-n, t-(n+1) ... t-1*: predict the state at time *t*) and is generally a task for a recurrent neural network. [Here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) is the great blog post by Andrej Karpathy about the topic that you should have a look at.

About your two questions:

1. This is hard to answer since the question of what optimizer to use highly depends on the input data. Generally speaking the network will converge no matter what optimizer you use. The time it takes to converge will differ however. Adaptive learning-rate methods, like Adagrad, Adadelta, and Adam tend to achieve convergence slightly faster. [Here](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#visualizationofalgorithms) is a good write-up of the different optimizers.
2. Basic neural networks (MLPs) don't do well with time series prediction. That would be an explanation for the low accuracy. However I don't know why the loss would be 0.

Comment: It's not really 0 of loss, just accuracy (loss is just low) here is an example of what I got. `Training Step: 460  | total loss: 0.00238 | time: 0.332s
| Adam | epoch: 006 | loss: 0.00238 - binary_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 8320/9999`

Comment: Why are you using binary accuracy?
Shouldn't the predicted value be between 0 and 200?

Comment: I don't know why it show this one, the predicted value should be between 0 and 200 (and even if the result I have right now are bad, they do are above 1). Here is the result at the end `Training Step: 7100  | total loss: 0.00304 | time: 1.385s
| Adam | epoch: 100 | loss: 0.00304 - binary_acc: 0.0000 | val_loss: 0.00260 - val_acc: 0.0000 -- iter: 8999/8999`

Comment: So I read up how `binary_accuracy` is computed and I think it's fine in this context. I have no explanation why the loss is this low. However you can see that it does not improve during training. That's an indication that your current network architecture does not converge.

Comment: This seem to the case, I'll try to see if I can find the reason of why it's not converging and will open a new question if I can't find anything. You answered this question perfectly, thank you.